# No. 3: What's the next in this letter sequence?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Part of a series of similar puzzles - the answer to one will give you the type of thinking required for the others.

What's the next letter in this series? What's the relationship?

```
u
d
t
c
c
s
s
o
n
d
o
d
t
```

To be explicit, note the `knowledge` tag below.

Comment: Did you come up with this sequence yourself?

Comment: The question is my own - the sequence should be at least familiar to around 400 million people

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> c (catorce) (We're counting in Spanish)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn the Informed badge?